# I have to compile hello.scala which has a import command "org.scala._"

Tags: java, scala, terminal

I know where this folder is located, how to run `hello.scala` from terminal

I am doing `scala hello.scala` and it generates an error

```
/Users/username/Desktop/hello/hello.scala:1: error: illegal start of definition
package org.scala
^

one error found
```

How can I run my program?

Comment: @reimeus my code doesn't do anything, i am just trying to figure out how to import other packages in my scala program hello.scala. I am using terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Include the package name when using the `scala` command and run it against the class file instead of the source code

```
scala org.scala.Hello
```

Like Java, [Scala Naming conventions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html) indicate that classes start with an initial *uppercase* letter for classes, e.g. `Hello`

Comment: and how should i do it if i am trying to import two packages
org.scala._ and org.scala.help._ in the same program.

Comment: Ensure that these are on the classpath both when youre compiling and running the application. It looks like those files are on the compilation path so you could use `scalac org/scala/*.scala` to compile

Comment: i am trying to set classpath using the command scala -c classpath /path_to_my_folder
and it says bad option: '-c'

Comment: Its `scala -cp classpath classname`. Also there's no need to use `-cp` if running from the directory where `org` resides (and you don't have any 3rd party JARs required to be added to the classpath)